# New to sql, how to insert column values into new column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, insert-select

What I have:

```
ALTER TABLE countryb
ADD gnppercap real
;


INSERT INTO countryb (gnppercap)
    SELECT gnp/population
    FROM countryb
;
```

I successfully created the column "`gnppercap`", now I want to populate values in every row with the variable. The new variable is the product of gnp and 1/population, with variables gnp and population already in the table I'm altering, *countryb*.

Here's the error:

```
ERROR: null value in column "code" violates not-null constraint
SQL state: 23502
Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, >null, null, null, null, 0.000263028).
```

I know that the table, countryb has a ton of non-null vars in it, so that's what those nulls are, I think.  I thought that since I specified the column I am inserting values into, it wouldn't matter...?

I'm lost. Help appreciated!

Comment: You added a column. It got whatever default value it should.  Now you want to change this value in already existing row.

Comment: Hence the use of "update", makes sense now.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to update the table, not insert a new row.

```
update countryb set gnppercap = gnp/population
```

As an aside: You probably don't want to store a calculated value in a separate column. What happens if you update gnp or population? Your gnppercap column will be inaccurate.

Comment: Wow yeah that was too easy, can't believe I missed it. 

Another question, sometimes the values are 0 in the numerator and denominator, I want to set these equal to null. How can I do that?

Comment: That would give you a null gnppercap. Your new column is probably null by default so there is no need to re-update that value to null.  I would do this instead: update countryb set gnppercap = gnp/population where gnp <> 0 and population <> 0